# Why jQuery has() is not working?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to develop a rating system.All is done. But, I could not displaying hover effect and mouse out effect. When the user will hover on star then he will put his cursor on a star, I will change the class, After then I will revert it as previous.

**Problem:**
If I add has(),hasClass(),find(),is() functions then It is not working.Is there any sequence for this jQuery function for putting thes ? Or What is the problem of my code ?

**HTML Code:**

```
   <ul class="ratingul">
      <? for($ii=1;$ii<=$k;$ii++){?>
        <li class="star ratings_star" title="<?=$ii?>"></li>
      <? }
      if($l>0){?>
        <li class="star_hf  ratings_star_half_full" title="<?=$ii++?>"></li>
      <?}
      for($jj=$ii;$jj<=5;$jj++){?>
        <li class="star_em ratings_star_empty" title="<?=$jj?>"></li>
      <? }
      ?>
    </ul>
```

**JS Code:**

```
 $('.ratingul li').hover(function(){
      $(this).has('.star_em').prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_star_empty');
      $(this).has('star_em').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_star');
  });

  $('.ratingul li').mouseout(function(){
      $(this).has('.star_em').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_star_empty');
      $(this).has('.star_em').prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_star');
  });
```

Comment: I think `has` `hasClass` & `is` returns Boolean values so you can't use like this

Comment: Please share the html

Comment: Note that the line `$(this).has('star_em')` is missing the dot for selecting the class, it should be `$(this).has('.star_em')`

Comment: Firstly, you have a typo in one spot `('star_em')` where you want `('.star_em')` like all the others. Secondly, I think you want to use `filter` not `has`

Comment: Seems like you could use a plain old `:hover` style and save some work...

Comment: @Mritunjay `.has()` does return a jQuery object with the matching elements: http://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: Actually, on second glance this is doing something a bit more complex than hover can handle.

Comment: @cafonso I just seen thanks for reference.

Comment: @BenLee Not really: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#custom and http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/ - only need JS to bind the relevant form element's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the actual answer from all of you, See my answer:

**JS:**

```
 $('.ratingul li').hover(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('star_em')){
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_star_empty');
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_star');
    }
});

$('.ratingul li').mouseout(function(){
        $('li').siblings('.star_em').addClass('ratings_star_empty');
        $('li').siblings('.star_em').removeClass('ratings_star');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of has() use filter():

```
$('.ratingul li').hover(function(){
    $(this).filter('.star_em').prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_star_empty');
    $(this).filter('.star_em').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_star');
});

$('.ratingul li').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).filter('.star_em').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_star_empty');
    $(this).filter('.star_em').prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_star');
});
```

Comment: I have follow this.But It is not working correctly. Could you review my html according to js ?

Comment: Can you add the rendered HTML instead of the PHP template?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this code, you may get the reslut what you expect.

```
$('.ratingul li').hover(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('star_em'))
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_star_empty');
    else
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_star');
 });

  $('.ratingul li').mouseout(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('star_em'))
     $(this).has('.star_em').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_star_empty');
     else
     $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_star');
  });
```